# Modify site URL in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

I have created a site collection and by mistake wrote an incorrect value to the site URL. I need to change the site URL from

> mysharepoint.com/**sites**/mysite

to

> mysharepoint.com/**tools**/mysite

Is it possible to achieve this without recreating the whole site?

Comment: You don't wanna change the sites URL as "/sites/" are just a managed path. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261845.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can do it. to do this this approach would be better.

for getting **tools** instead of **sites** in the url you need to create a managed path in central admin. Below image will show the way to create managed path.

[image]

Next Step create site collection ends with **mysite** by selecting newly created managed path **tools** instead of **sites**.

Take a backup of old site collection url

> mysharepoint.com/sites/mysite

and delete the old site collection and restore backup to newly created url

> mysharepoint.com/tools/mysite

Comment: Thanks for your response. I wanted to pass by the need of backup and restore, but it seems there no any other way.

Comment: Just performed the steps mentioned by you, worked like a charm :) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you could change the subsite url through UI and change the site collection url through powershell.In your case, you have to use Powershell.

Give it a try by using "Rename" command.

```
$site = Get-SPSite <Site URL>
$site.Rename("<New Site URL>")
```

**A little catch**
There is a little catch to this. You can only use this to rename site collection URL’s that
– Use “Wildcard inclusion” Managed Paths.
– Are Host named site collections (In which case you could also use Set-SPSiteURL)

You can’t use it to change http://sharepoint/sites/marketing to http://sharepoint/marketing (Even if the Explicit inclusion managed path exists).

Comment: I saw the same explanation here in the article http://www.sharepointrelated.com/2015/03/30/change-site-collection-url-sharepoint/ but it guides to change the site name not the site url. Do you think this will work in my case as well?